# Powerpoint: Manually set Slide Name

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

**Context:**
A PowerPoint slide in C# has a property Slide.Name (usually contains an arbitrary string value).
In my C# application I would like to use this property to identify slides (the slide order is to unreliable).

**Question:**
How can I manually set the Slide.Name property in the PowerPoint Application?

My problem is very like to the: “[How to name an object within a PowerPoint slide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074209/how-to-name-an-object-within-a-powerpoint-slide)” but just on the slide level.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

There is no built-in functionality in PowerPoint that allows you to edit the name of a slide. As Steve mentioned, you have to do it using VBA code. The slide *name* will never change due to inserting more slides, and it will stay the same even if you close PowerPoint; the slide name set in VBA code is persistent. Here's some code I wrote to allow you to easily view the name of the currently selected slide and allow you to rename it:

```vb
'------------------------------------------------------------------
' NameSlide()
'
' Renames the current slide so you can refer to this slide in
' VBA by name. This is not used as part of the application;
' it is for maintenance and for use only by developers of
' the PowerPoint presentation.
'
' 1. In Normal view, click on the slide you wish to rename
' 2. ALT+F11 to VB Editor
' 3. F5 to run this subroutine
'------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub NameSlide()
    Dim curName As String
    curName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.name
    
    Dim newName As String
retry:
    newName = InputBox("Enter the new name for slide '" + curName + "', or press Cancel to keep existing name.", "Rename slide")
    If Trim(newName) = "" Then Exit Sub
            
    Dim s As Slide
    
    ' check if this slide name already exists
    On Error GoTo SlideNotFound
    Set s = ActivePresentation.Slides(newName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    MsgBox "Slide with this name already exists!"
    GoTo retry
    
    Exit Sub
    
SlideNotFound:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.name = newName
    MsgBox "Slide renamed to '" + newName + "'."
        
End Sub
```

Comment: This script is very useful for VBA programming: it lets you rename any slide so that you can reliably use the slide name in your VBA code.

Answer (score 6):

You can't manually set the slide name, but with a bit of code, it's simple.  In VBA, for example:

```
Sub NameThatSlide()
  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Name = "Whatever You Like Here"
End Sub
```

Comment: This does effectively change the name of the slide in the Slide Presentation Edit window.  However, in the VBA Editor, the slides *still* appear with their *original* names, e.g., "Slide1" and "Slide 32" etc.  There are gaps where slides are deleted.  Is there a way to get the name shown in the VBAProject "Microsoft PowerPoint Object" list to change to be congruent with the .Name property of the slide (in PowerPoint 2013)?

Comment: I don't believe there is.  PowerPoint names each slide when it's created.  Each slide also has a .Name property, which PPT sets to the same string as the slide's name initially.  It's this .Name property, not the internal name of the slide, that changes when we set the .Name.  It *might* be possible to change the internal name by editing the presentation XML.  I'm curious:  what's the need for changing the name?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Steve Rindsberg. The "need" is for ease of programming in VBA. I have a "presentation" which will be a training tool for students. It will be entirely controlled by VBA so the VBA code controls when the student is allowed to continue on to the next slide, etc. Because I've re-arranged the order of slides and done a large number of "test" slides, it is confusing working with the slide in the edit view where the slide has a sensible name but then switching to the VBAProject view where the slide has just a number that does not coincide with the name in the edit view.

Comment: If it's a matter of controlling what happens when the student clicks a button on a slide,  you might be better off using regular shapes that you've  assigned a Run Macro action setting to instead of ActiveX stuff.  If you start the macro off with something like Sub RunMe(oSh as Shape) you'll get a reference to the clicked shape in oSh.  oSh.Parent then gives you a reference to the slide the shape's on.  You can nearly always code it in such a way that you don't need to maintain different batches of code for each ActiveX shape.  And it's more reliable.

Comment: Thanks again, @Steve Rindsberg.  I should probably take your advice!  :)  Thing is, the code is fairly complicated, e.g., changing the order of the multiple choice items each time the presentation is run, making the backend easy to re-write items in the code instead of in the shapes since different shapes will have different answers each run, having code determine and require responses recording 1-second accuracy, code that uses text-to-speech with speech markup language, re-presenting slides answered incorrectly,  etc. So, I'd love the slide names to match, well, the slide .name property!

Answer (score 3):

You can rename a slide manually or with VBA. Once you know how, the door opens to some interesting possibilities, which I will demonstrate with code below.

Manually renaming slides.  This ability is hidden in the VBA Editor's Properties pane, but it does *not* require coding.

1. If the Developer ribbon is not visible, enable it: **File** > **Options** > **Customize Ribbon** > check the **Developer** Main Tab.
2. From the **Developer** ribbon, click the **Visual Basic** menu item to open the Visual Basic Editor.
3. Press the **Ctrl+R** keys to navigate to the Project Explorer pane.
4. Expand "**Microsoft PowerPoint Objects**"
5. Click on any slide to select it.
6. Press the **F4** key to navigate to the Properties pane.
7. Edit the **(Name)** item, and press **Enter** to apply the name change.

The slide name change may not appear immediately in the VBA Project Explorer pane.  As long as the name is correct in the Properties pane, the name changed successfully.

This VBA code will also do the trick (hide slide number 1):

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue
```

This code block covers a few ways to manage slide names and answers the main question.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function RenameSlide(oldName As String, newName As String)
' RenameSlide finds slide oldName and renames it to newName.
' Arguements:
'   oldName: current (old) name of existing slide
'   newName: new name for slide.
'
    Dim tempBool As Boolean
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim RetVal(0 To 1) As String

    ' Check if oldName can be found.
    If SlideExists(oldName) Then
        Set sld = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(oldName)
    Else
        RetVal(0) = 1 'Error 1
        RetVal(1) = "Error 1: slide with name " & oldName & " not found. Aborting."
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Check if this slide name newName already exists.
    If SlideExists(newName) Then
        RetVal(0) = 2 'Error 1
        RetVal(1) = "Error 2: slide with name " & newName & " already exists. Aborting."
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Rename the slide
    'Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(oldName) = newName
    Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(oldName).Select
    Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name = newName 'current slide
    RetVal(0) = 0 'Success
    RetVal(1) = "Success: slide renamed from '" & oldName & "' to '" & newName & "'."

End Function

Public Sub SetSlideName()
' Prompt user for new name for active slide.
'
    Dim oldName As String
    Dim newName As String
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim msg As String

    ' Get current name of active slide.
    oldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name

    msg = "Enter the new name for slide '" + oldName + "'."
retry:
    newName = ""
    ' Prompt for new slide name. Loop until a name of at least 1 character is provided.
    Do While newName = ""
        newName = InputBox(msg, "Rename slide")
        newName = Trim(newName)
        If Len(newName) = 0 Then
            msg = "Try again.  You must enter a slide name to continue."
        ElseIf newName = oldName Or newName = Str(vbCancel) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop

    ' If an existing slide already has name newName, then
    ' go back and prompt user again.slide name already exists
    If SlideExists(newName) Then
        msg = "Slide with this name already exists!"
        GoTo retry
    End If

    ' Set the new slide name
    Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name = newName
    MsgBox "Slide renamed to '" + newName + "'."
End Sub

Public Function SlideExists(SlideName As String) As Boolean
    Dim RetVal As Boolean
    Dim sld

    ' Assume slide does not exist.
    SlideExists = False

    ' Try to find slide by name.
    ' If we error out, the slide does NOT exist.
    On Error GoTo NoSlide
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideName)

    ' If we got this far, the slide DOES exist.
    SlideExists = True
    Exit Function

NoSlide:
    ' Error setting slide objects shows
    ' that slides does NOT exist.
    SlideExists = False
End Function
```

As an aside, I use the slide naming trick and a little VBA to selectively remove certain slides from printing.  I added a few extra VBA macros for the sake of populating the Macros list. From any slide: Developer ribbon > Macros > Select Macro > Run button.  Use this method to kick off my PresentSlide, DontPresentSlide, PrintSlide and DontPrintSlide macros.  Once you have properly tagged your various slides, simply run the PrepToPresentSlides or PrepToPrintSlides macro before you present or print, respectively.

Play around with these macros a bit and read the comments.  You will find that I wrote the code extensibly, so you can modify it easily for your needs.

The code below helps me to manage which slides and objects are printed and which are presented on-screen.  This is particularly useful when I want to print reference slides but not cover them.  It is even more useful when I have slides with animations.  Animations don't usually translate print well. So, I choose not to print some animated objects at all.  In fact, I can even add in substitute content for the objects to be used just for printing (hidden when presenting) - though I rarely do this.  Instead, I will typically hide the animation from printing or create a slide to present and a non-animated copy of it for print.  With these macros, it is easy to manage a mix and match of slides and objects for print and slides and objects for presentation.  I hope you enjoy.

```
Option Explicit

' DontPresentSlide - run macro while on a slide you wish to skip while presenting.
'                    The slide name will be appended with "NoPresent". You still
'                    need to run PrepToPresent before presenting to hide slide.
' PresentSlide - "NoPresent" will be removed from the slide. You still
'                need to run PrepToPresent before presenting to hide slide.
' PrepToPesentSlides() - Unhide slides and objects you want presented and
'                hide slides and objects you do NOT want presented.
' ShowNoPressnt() - show slides and shapes marked "NoPresent"
' HideNoPresent() - hide slides and shapes marked "NoPresent"

' DontPrintSlide - run macro while on a slide you wish to skip while presenting.
'                    The slide name will be appended with "NoPrint". You still
'                    need to run PrepToPresent before presenting to hide slide.
' PrintSlide - "NoPrint" will be removed from the slide. You still
'                need to run PrepToPresent before presenting to hide slide.
' PrepToPrintSlides() - Unhide slides and objects you want printed and
'                hide slides and objects you do NOT want printed.
' ShowNoPrint() - show slides and shapes marked "NoPrint"
' HideNoPrint() - hide slides and shapes marked "NoPrint"

' ShowHideSlides() - Hide or Unhide slides based on slide name.
' ShowHideShapes() - Hide or Unhide shapes based on shapes name.


Public Const cjaHide = False
Public Const cjaShow = True
Public Const cjaToggle = 2

Sub ShowHideSlides(NameContains As String _
                , Optional LMR As String = "R" _
                , Optional ShowSlide As Integer = False)
' Show or Hide slides based on slide name.
' Arguements:
'   NameContains (string):
'       slides with this string will be modified.
'   LMR (string): enter L, M or R to indicate
'       searching the Left, Middle or Right of
'       the slide name, respectively.
'   ShowSlide (integer):
'       Show: True (-1)
'       Hide: False (0)
'       Toggle: 2
'
' To show or hide slides manually:
'   Right-click the slide thumbnail, then click Hide Slide
' To rename slides,
'   Use this VBA: ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name = "NewSlideName"
'   Or, edit the (Name) property in the VBA Properties window.
'
   Dim sldCurrent As Slide
   Dim found As Boolean
   found = False

   LMR = Trim(UCase(LMR))
   If LMR <> "L" And LMR <> "M" Then LMR = "R"
   'Loop through each slide in presentation.
   For Each sldCurrent In ActivePresentation.Slides
        'Match shape name left, right or middle as per LMR arguement.
        'ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name or Slide.SlideNumber
        found = False
        If LMR = "R" And LCase(right(sldCurrent.Name, Len(NameContains))) = LCase(NameContains) Then
            found = True
        ElseIf LMR = "L" And LCase(left(sldCurrent.Name, Len(NameContains))) = LCase(NameContains) Then
            found = True
        ElseIf LMR = "M" And InStr(1, LCase(NameContains), LCase(sldCurrent.Name)) Then
            found = True
        End If
        'If match found, then set shape visibility per ShowShape arguement.
        If found Then
            If ShowSlide = True Then
                ActivePresentation.Slides(sldCurrent.SlideNumber).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse
            ElseIf ShowSlide = False Then
                ActivePresentation.Slides(sldCurrent.SlideNumber).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue
            Else
                ActivePresentation.Slides(sldCurrent.SlideNumber).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = Not ActivePresentation.Slides(sldCurrent.SlideNumber).SlideShowTransition.Hidden
            End If
        End If
    Next       'sldCurrent
End Sub

Sub ShowHideShapes(NameContains As String _
                , Optional LMR As String = "R" _
                , Optional ShowShape As Integer = False)
' Show or Hide shapes/objects based on object name.
' Arguements:
'   NameContains (string):
'       shapes with this string will be modified.
'   LMR (string): enter L, M or R to indicate
'       searching the Left, Middle or Right of
'       the slide name, respectively.
'   ShowSlide (integer):
'       Show: True (-1)
'       Hide: False (0)
'       Toggle: 2
'
' To show, hide and/or rename objects:
'    1. Turn on Selection Pane via: Home Ribbon >
'       Select > Selection Pane.
'    2. Double-click a shape name to rename it.
'    3. Click the eye icon to the far right to show/hide a shape.

   Dim shpCurrent As Shape
   Dim sldCurrent As Slide
   Dim found As Boolean
   found = False

   LMR = Trim(UCase(LMR))
   If LMR <> "L" And LMR <> "M" Then LMR = "R"
   'Loop through each slide in presentation.
   For Each sldCurrent In ActivePresentation.Slides
      With sldCurrent
          'Loop through each shape on current slide.
          For Each shpCurrent In .Shapes
            'Match shape name left, right or middle as per LMR arguement.
            found = False
            If LMR = "R" And right(shpCurrent.Name, Len(NameContains)) = NameContains Then
                found = True
            ElseIf LMR = "L" And left(shpCurrent.Name, Len(NameContains)) = NameContains Then
                found = True
            ElseIf LMR = "M" And InStr(1, NameContains, shpCurrent.Name) Then
                found = True
            End If
            'If match found, then set shape visibility per ShowShape arguement.
            If found Then
                If ShowShape = True Then
                    shpCurrent.Visible = True
                ElseIf ShowShape = False Then
                    shpCurrent.Visible = False
                Else
                    shpCurrent.Visible = Not shpCurrent.Visible
                End If
            End If
          Next 'sldCurrent
      End With 'sldCurrent
    Next       'sldCurrent

End Sub

Sub HideNoPrint()
' Hide slides and shapes you do NOT want printed.
'
' Run this macro to hide all slides and shapes that
' end with the string "NoPrint".

' Usage.  Assume you have slides that contain animations that
' make the printed slide difficult or impossible to read.
' Let's further suppose you plan to present certain slides
' but not print them.
'   1. Add the"NoPrint" suffix to any shapes that clutter
'      the printed page.
'   2. Add the "NoPrint" suffix to slides you don't want to
'      print.
'   3. Run this macro to hide shapes and slides.
'   4. Print the slides.
'   5. Optionally, run the ShowNoPrint() macro in preparation
'      for presenting the slides.
    ShowHideShapes "NoPrint", "R", False
    ShowHideSlides "NoPrint", "R", False
End Sub

Sub ShowNoPrint()
' Unhide slides and shapes that were hidden
' to prevent them from being printed in handouts.
'
    ShowHideShapes "NoPrint", "P", True
    ShowHideSlides "NoPrint", "P", True
End Sub

Sub HideNoPressent()
' Hide objects you do NOT want to present on screen.
'
' Run this macro to hide all slides and shapes that
' end with the string "NoPresent".
'
' Usage.  Assume you have slides that contain supporting material
' that you wish to provide as printed handouts but not show.
' You can manually hide those slides and objects of course. I
' prefer to use these macros.
'   1. Add the"NoPresent" suffix to any shapes that you want
'      to print to handouts but not show on-screen.
'   2. Add the "NoPresent" suffix to slides you want to
'      print but not display on screen, such as reference slides.
'   3. Run this macro to hide the "NoPresent" shapes and slides.
'   4. Present your slides.
'   5. Optionally, run the ShowNoPresent() macro in preparation
'      for printing the slides.
'
    ShowHideShapes "NoPressent", "R", False
    ShowHideSlides "NoPressent", "R", False
End Sub

Sub ShowNoPresent()
' Unhide objects that were hidden to prevent them from
' being presented on screen.
'
    ShowHideShapes "NoPressent", "P", True
    ShowHideSlides "NoPressent", "P", True
End Sub

Sub PrepToPrintSlides()
' Unhide objects you want printed and
' hide objects you do NOT want printed.
    ShowNoPresent
    HideNoPrint
End Sub

Sub PrepToPresentSlides()
' Unhide objects you want presented and
' hide objects you do NOT want presented.
    ShowNoPrint
    HideNoPresent
End Sub

Sub DontPresentSlide()
    Dim RetVal, sldName As String
    sldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
    If InStr(1, sldName, "NoPresent", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        RetVal = RenameSlide(sldName, sldName & "-NoPresent")
    End If
    HideNoPresent
End Sub

Sub PresentSlide()
    Dim RetVal, sldName As String, strStart As String, newName As String
    'Remove the NoPresent suffix from the current slide.

    'get slide name
    sldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
    'Unhide slide
    ActivePresentation.Slides(sldName).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse
    'remove "-NoPresent" from slide name
    Do
        strStart = InStr(1, sldName, "-NoPresent")
        If InStr(1, sldName, "-NoPresent") Then
            newName = left(sldName, strStart - 1) & right(sldName, Len(sldName) - strStart - 9)
            RetVal = RenameSlide(sldName, newName)
        End If
        sldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
    Loop Until InStr(1, sldName, "-NoPresent") = 0
    'remove "NoPresent" from slide name
    Do
        strStart = InStr(1, sldName, "NoPresent")
        If InStr(1, sldName, "NoPresent") Then
            newName = left(sldName, strStart - 1) & right(sldName, Len(sldName) - strStart - 8)
            RetVal = RenameSlide(sldName, newName)
        End If
        sldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
    Loop Until InStr(1, sldName, "NoPresent") = 0

End Sub

Sub DontPrintSlide()
    Dim RetVal, sldName As String
    sldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
    If InStr(1, sldName, "NoPrint", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        RetVal = RenameSlide(sldName, sldName & "-NoPrint")
    End If
    HideNoPrint
End Sub

Sub PrintSlide()
    Dim RetVal, sldName As String, strStart As String, newName As String
    'Remove the NoPrint suffix from the current slide.

    'get slide name
    sldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
    'Unhide slide
    ActivePresentation.Slides(sldName).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoFalse
    'remove "-NoPrint" from slide name
    Do
        strStart = InStr(1, sldName, "-NoPrint")
        If InStr(1, sldName, "-NoPrint") Then
            newName = left(sldName, strStart - 1) & right(sldName, Len(sldName) - strStart - 7)
            RetVal = RenameSlide(sldName, newName)
        End If
        sldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
    Loop Until InStr(1, sldName, "-NoPrint") = 0
    'remove "NoPrint" from slide name
    Do
        strStart = InStr(1, sldName, "NoPrint")
        If InStr(1, sldName, "NoPrint") Then
            newName = left(sldName, strStart - 1) & right(sldName, Len(sldName) - strStart - 6)
            RetVal = RenameSlide(sldName, newName)
        End If
        sldName = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Name
    Loop Until InStr(1, sldName, "NoPrint") = 0
End Sub

Sub HideAllCovers()
' Run this macro to hide all Covers.
    ShowHideShapes "Cover", "L", False
End Sub

Sub ShowAllCovers()
' Run this macro to hide all Covers.
    ShowHideShapes "Cover", "L", True
End Sub

Sub HideAllAnswers()
' Run this macro to hide all Covers.
    ShowHideShapes "Answer", "L", False
End Sub

Sub ShowAllAnswers()
' Run this macro to hide all Covers.
    ShowHideShapes "Answer", "L", True
End Sub

Sub HideAllQuestions()
' Run this macro to hide all Covers.
    ShowHideShapes "Question", "L", False
End Sub

Sub ShowAllQuestions()
' Run this macro to hide all Covers.
    ShowHideShapes "Question", "L", True
End Sub

Sub ShowAll()
' Run this macro to hide all shapes (Covers and Answers).
    ShowAllQuestions
    ShowAllAnswers
    ShowAllCovers
    ShowNoPrint
End Sub

Sub HideAll()
' Run this macro to hide all shapes (Covers and Answers).
    HideAllQuestions
    HideAllAnswers
    HideAllCovers
    HideNoPrint
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "Developer" tab in "File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon" (Details: https://www.addintools.com/documents/powerpoint/where-is-developer-tab.html)

In the developer tab, follow these steps and see the image below (in Portuguese, sorry)

- Enter the developer tab
- Select the target slide
- If you don't have any active X control (buttons, textboxes, etc.) in the slide, add a dummy button from the developer tab
- Select this button on the slide and click "properties" at the developer tab
- At the top of the properties window, there is a combo box where you can select the slide instead of the button
- Select the slide and see its programming properties, including name

[image]

Comment: Sorry to revive this old post. Is there any other way to see the Slide name, other than this method?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that this will enable you to set the Slide.Name property because I'm not a VBA programmer, but anyway AFAIK the easiest way to name slides in PowerPoint 2010 is using Outline view.

If you position your mouse farthest left on a created slide, you can drag rightwards a kind of vertical slide sorter. At the top of that pane, you'll see two tabs: **Slides** and **Outline**.

Select **Outline**, you'll see each slide numbered and a grey grab button which allows you to reorder your slides. If you click to the right of that, you can type in whatever name you like, say **Home**.

In the main view pane, the slide will then have **Home** emblazoned across it. You can then either leave it there, or conceal it by altering the font colour to the background or by moving the text outside the presentation frame.

BTW You can use these names in hyperlinks.

Comment: While there may be some reason to do this, it unfortunately doesn't actually change the slide's  `.Name` property.

Answer (score 1):

used the Sub SplitFile() function to create individual slides from a deck of >100 slides. All went well!! But can anyone tell me what code do I use to rename the file automatically, assuming that each slide has a title in a text box? I want the slide title to be the file name for the new, individual slide created.

Here's the code I used to create individual slides (as individual files), thanks to whoever posted it online.

Sub SplitFile()
    Dim lSlidesPerFile As Long
    Dim lTotalSlides As Long
    Dim oSourcePres As Presentation
    Dim otargetPres As Presentation
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sExt As String
    Dim sBaseName As String
    Dim lCounter As Long
    Dim lPresentationsCount As Long     ' how many will we split it into
    Dim x As Long
    Dim lWindowStart As Long
    Dim lWindowEnd As Long
    Dim sSplitPresName As String

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set oSourcePres = ActivePresentation
If Not oSourcePres.Saved Then
    MsgBox "Please save your presentation then try again"
    Exit Sub
End If

lSlidesPerFile = CLng(InputBox("How many slides per file?", "Split Presentation"))
lTotalSlides = oSourcePres.Slides.Count
sFolder = ActivePresentation.Path & "\"
sExt = Mid$(ActivePresentation.Name, InStr(ActivePresentation.Name, ".") + 1)
sBaseName = Mid$(ActivePresentation.Name, 1, InStr(ActivePresentation.Name, ".") - 1)

If (lTotalSlides / lSlidesPerFile) - (lTotalSlides \ lSlidesPerFile) > 0 Then
    lPresentationsCount = lTotalSlides \ lSlidesPerFile + 1
Else
    lPresentationsCount = lTotalSlides \ lSlidesPerFile
End If

If Not lTotalSlides > lSlidesPerFile Then
    MsgBox "There are fewer than " & CStr(lSlidesPerFile) & " slides in this presentation."
    Exit Sub
End If

For lCounter = 1 To lPresentationsCount

    ' which slides will we leave in the presentation?
    lWindowEnd = lSlidesPerFile * lCounter
    If lWindowEnd > oSourcePres.Slides.Count Then
        ' odd number of leftover slides in last presentation
        lWindowEnd = oSourcePres.Slides.Count
        lWindowStart = ((oSourcePres.Slides.Count \ lSlidesPerFile) * lSlidesPerFile) + 1
    Else
        lWindowStart = lWindowEnd - lSlidesPerFile + 1
    End If

    ' Make a copy of the presentation and open it

    For Each oSlide In ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides
strTitles = strTitles _
    & "Slide: " _
    & CStr(oSlide.SlideIndex) & vbCrLf _
    & oSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
```

Next oSlide
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

intFileNum = FreeFile

sSplitPresName = sFolder & sBaseName & _
               "_" & CStr(lWindowStart) & "-" & CStr(lWindowEnd) & "." & sExt
        oSourcePres.SaveCopyAs sSplitPresName, ppSaveAsDefault
        Set otargetPres = Presentations.Open(sSplitPresName, , , True)

```
    With otargetPres
        For x = .Slides.Count To lWindowEnd + 1 Step -1
            .Slides(x).Delete
        Next
        For x = lWindowStart - 1 To 1 Step -1
            .Slides(x).Delete
        Next
        .Save
        .Close
    End With

Next    ' lpresentationscount
```

NormalExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error encountered"
    Resume NormalExit
End Sub