# Can't find "Microsoft PowerPoint Objects" in Powerpoint VBA Interface

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I followed [Powerpoint: Manually set Slide Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855306/powerpoint-manually-set-slide-name)
but still can't see "Microsoft PowerPoint Objects" (I use latest Office 2017)

[image]

Comment: Experienced same trouble. I found an object explorer through [F2] shortcut, but was not a massive help. Did you find an answer so far?