# Overwrite when paste to powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

If i have texts(shapes) in my powerpoint. How can i modify my code NOT to create a new shape but overwrite the value inside it.

The code below creates a new shape.
Any Ideas?

```
Private Sub test()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\ELE_powerpoint\book1.xlsx", True, False)

With xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet
xlWorkBook.sheets(1).Range("A2").Copy
End With

ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste.Select

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets use a variable instead of copying and pasting like this

```
mytext = xlWorkBook.sheets(1).Range("A2")
```

you can then set the text value of a shape like this

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Shape name").TextFrame.Characters.Text = myText
```

read about how to set the name of a shape here: [How to name an object within a PowerPoint slide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074209/how-to-name-an-object-within-a-powerpoint-slide)

Comment: Going with a variable rather than copy/pasting is probably the way to go. +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the index of the shape you want to paste into. Say it is index 2

Then use

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Paste
```