# Accessing Textbox value

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint

I am trying to make an automatic textbox checker.

I want it to ensure that there are at least 30 characters in each textbox before allowing the user to move to the next page. How do I access the values of the textboxes?

The specific piece of code

`ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex).Shapes("TextBox" & CStr(i)).Characters.Text`

```
Public Sub GeneralCheck()

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim TextBoxCounter As Integer
    TextBoxCounter = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For i = 1 To 4
    
        Set oSh = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex).Shapes("TextBox" & CStr(i))
        If Err.Number = 0 Then  ' shape exists
            MsgBox ("I exist")
            MsgBox (Str(Len(ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("TextBox" & CStr(i)).Characters.Text)))
            TextBoxCounter = TextBoxCounter + 1
        Else
            MsgBox ("I don't exist")
        End If
    
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Update:
Changed code still cannot access the text of the TextBox.

```
Set oSh = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("TextBox" & CStr(i))
If Err.Number = 0 Then  ' shape exists
    MsgBox ("I exist")
    ShapeLength = ShapeLength + Len(oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
    MsgBox (ShapeLength)
```

The For loop seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must [set the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074209) of the Shape:
2. Get the `Shape` Object:
   By name: `oShape = oSlide.Shapes("NameOfShape")`.
   By index: `oShape = oSlide.Shapes(index)`.
3. To access the text of a shape:

   ```
   oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
   ```

Comment: Using this, MsgBox (Str(Len(ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex).Shapes("TextBox" & CStr(i)).TextFrame.TextRange.Text))) . However it is still not working

Comment: Is exist name of shape "TextBox1"?

Comment: If you not setting name, you have to use index, ex: slide.Shapes(1)

Comment: There is definitely an object on my slide 2 which has the name "TextBox1

Comment: When I run my code I get four message boxes one with "I exist" and three with "I dont exist" as expected. I just get no message box telling me the length of the text in textbox1

Comment: Press:  ALT + F10 and check name of your shapes.

Comment: "TextBox1" is the name of the textbox, I would not get the I exist msgBox if not

Comment: Exist TextBox2,3,4 on your slide?

Comment: No only text box 1, I can try put them in as well and try it out

Comment: You accessing TextBox1,2,3,4: by your code: .Shapes("TextBox" & CStr(i))

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, is that where i am going wrong?

Comment: Yes, your slide not exist TextBox2,3,4 and you accessing them.

Comment: I designed the code to see if "TextBox1" Exists, and if it does then to print the length of the text? How do I change it to work

Comment: You can remove For and change .Shapes ("TextBox" & CStr (i)) to .Shapes ("TextBox1"), and refer my answer to get text.

Comment: @D T that removes the functionality that I am trying to get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217300/discussion-between-theouz-and-d-t).

Answer (score 0):

The code i required to get the value of the text box was

```
oShape.OLEFormat.Object.Value
```