# PowerPoint: Add Date of Yesterday and Tomorrow to a Slide

Tags: date, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

I want to have a table on my PowerPoint (2016) slide which should look like this:

| sysdate - 1 | sysdate | sysdate + 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02.09.2021 | 03.09.2021 | 04.09.2021 |

To keep the slides intuitive, the dates should be updated automatically.

By using `Insert -> Text -> Date & Time` I can add a field containing the current date for the center column.

**How do I add a dynamic field for yesterday and tomorrow?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, follow [the steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074209/how-to-name-an-object-within-a-powerpoint-slide) to name your table. After that, insert a module (Alt+F11, Insert - Module) and add this piece of code:

```
Sub SetTableHeaders()
    
    Const SlideNo = 1
    Const TableName = "TableName Here"
    
    Dim MyTable As Table
    Set MyTable = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideNo).Shapes(TableName).Table
    
    MyTable.Rows(1).Cells(1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now - 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    MyTable.Rows(1).Cells(2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    MyTable.Rows(1).Cells(3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Format(Now + 1, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
End Sub
```

Replace the `SlideNo` and `TableName` values with the right ones. Run it (F5) to set the headers.

Comment: The code seems to work. But it is not executed automatically. Can I make it run automatically, if "SlideNo" is shown?

Comment: `Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = SlideNo Then
        SetTableHeaders
    End If
End Sub` did the trick